# How to convert Json in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I am using c#.net with ASP.Net MVC.
I have following code

```
var lstrelations = _people.GetAllUsers();
List<string> lstEmailAddresses = lstrelations.Select(p =>p.EmailID).ToList<string>();

return Json(lstEmailAddresses, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This is generating output like

```
["xxy@xct.com", "text13@tds.com", "sdxxa@xys.com"]
```

but I want generate Json like

```
["EmailID:xxy@xct.com", "EmailID:text13@tds.com", "EmailID:sdxxa@xys.com"]
```

I want to put name of each address like "EmailID"

Comment: `var result = lstrelations.Select(p =>new {EmailID = p.EmailID).ToList();`

Comment: you mean like this?[{EmailID:"xxy@xct.com"},{ EmailID:"text13@tds.com"}, {EmailID:"sdxxa@xys.com"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code...

```
var lstrelations = _people.GetAllUsers();
var lstEmailAddresses = lstrelations.Select(p => new { EmailID = p.EmailID }).ToList();
Json(lstEmailAddresses, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```